# Joomla. Text is hide and I don't know where it is

Tags: text, joomla, hide

I have a website in Joomla and somebody has hacked me and has added some “advertisement-text” to my web next to the logo or around it.

My website has 7 items on the menu and all of them have the same article, I mean, it does not matter if you press on one or another, it will always come up the same information.

The point is that when I press on the first item, the log does not appears in his place because in that area(logo or around it), is the “advertisement-text” inserted. This “advertisement-text” is hide but it is there. If I click on the sixth item, everything is the same, except that the “advertisement-text” appears.

The remaining of the items, everything appears correctly although the “advertisement-text” is hide(display: none) on the website.

I have seen “article manager”, “Module manager”, I have changed and re-install the template and nothing happens, the “advertisement-text” is still there.

I think that the hacker has added the “advertisement-text” manually in a particular file and that file is loaded every time when somebody access to the website. I have seen the files and folders on the server but I could not find where the hacker inserted that piece of code. Besides, I think that the text is encrypted, so in the files it will appear something like “base64(“encripted text”).

Does somebody know where the hacker could have inserted that “advertisement-text”? If I could avoid re-installing Joomla, it would be lovely.

Many thanks

Comment: I guess you are using some vulnerable joomla extension. the text will be in the  template.

Comment: if you will provide a link then it will be easier to help you

Comment: But, if the text would be in the template, after changing the template that text-adversimente should disappear and it doesn't

Comment: Then it must be a malware,please scan your site with the securi  - https://sitecheck.sucuri.net

Comment: provide your website url, it should be because of some plugins